# Ошибка при трансляции запроса к полю типа "inet" в postgreSql через linq и EF Core

Tags: c#, postgresql, linq, entity-framework-core

У меня есть класс Entity, который содержит свойство `Ipaddr` типа `IPАddress`. В базу postgresql оно сохраняется в поле типа `inet`, как и задумывалось. Для поиска по этому полю использую такой метод:

```
 public async Task<Switch?> GetSwitch(string ip)
        {
            return await context.Switches.Where(s => 
                      s.Ipaddr.ToString() == ip).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }
```

При его вызове возникает ошибка:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(s => s.Ipaddr.ToString() == __ip_0)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,
> or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to
> 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как переписать код, чтобы Linq смог транслировать запрос к БД. Получать всю коллекцию, а потом ее фильтровать на стороне клиента не хочется, так как может быть очень много данных.

Answer (score 1):

На английском СО [рекомендуют](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3292773/8324991) для конвертации поля в строку на стороне `SQL` использовать функцию `SqlFunctions.StringConvert`. Видимо, в вашем случае будет как-то так:

```cs
public async Task<Switch?> GetSwitch(string ip)
{
    return await context.Switches.Where(s => 
        SqlFunctions.StringConvert(s.Ipaddr) == ip).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но насколько я понял это для SqlServer, а не Postgresql и для EF, а не EF Core

Comment: @Vladal Ну там если в том посте по ссылке пройти и переключить на `Core`, то функция никуда не денется. Вот насчёт `Posrgresql` это да, может быть по-другому, нужно читать, что там есть. Я бы на вашем месте попробовал, вдруг заработает.